# Is there a way to hide/show a linkbutton on an action panel depending on each row

Tags: c#, asp.net, panel, ascx

Currently I have a method in my code-behind that handles the functionality of showing or hiding an image in a certain column of my grid-view depending on a data value. By these same conditions, I want to hide or show a link button that is in my action panel that can be brought up on each row. Right now I am simply setting the visibility of the link-button that I want to show/hide within that same aforementioned method.

But of course what happens is it sets the visibility for that link-button for all of the rows instances of the action panel. for instance if on the last row in the gridview, that function is enacted (like it is on every row) but the conditions are met there for the linkbuttons visibility to be false, then the visibility is false for all rows.

Is there a way to set the visibility individually per row?

some of the relevent ascx

```
     <div class="actionPanelWrapper" id="actionPanelItem">
            <div class="actionPanelOverlap"></div>
            <div class="actionPanel">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="linkbuttonDetails" Text="Details" OnClick="actionPanel_Click" CommandName="details"></asp:LinkButton></li>
                    <li>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="linkbuttonViewApprovers" Text="View Approvers" OnClick="actionPanel_Click" CommandName="viewapprovers"></asp:LinkButton></li>                       
                    <li>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="linkbuttonActionEdit" Text="View Attachments" OnClick="actionPanel_Click" CommandName="attachments"></asp:LinkButton></li>

                    <li>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="linkbuttonComments" Text="View / Add Comments" OnClick="actionPanel_Click" CommandName="Comments"></asp:LinkButton></li>
                    <%--<li><a onclick="actionPanelEventHistoryShow(this);" href="#">View Request History</a></li>--%>
                    <li> <asp:LinkButton ID="lbEventHistory" runat="server" Text="View Request History" OnClick="actionPanel_Click" CommandName="history"></asp:LinkButton>    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The ImageButton Method call in which I piggybacked and tried adding the visibility setting on the linkbutton as mentioned

```
Visible='<%# GetStatusImageVisibility(Eval("StatusName").ToString(), Eval("IsRejected").ToString())%>'
```

The Codebehind method

```
 protected bool GetStatusImageVisibility(string Status, string IsRejected)
    {
        if (Status == "SAVED" && IsRejected != "1")
        {
            linkbuttonViewApprovers.Visible = false;
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            linkbuttonViewApprovers.Visible = true;
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Technically you add some logic in your 1st method where you hide/show images to do so. Convert your column with the linkbutton into a template column. Based on your condition in your OnRowDatabound method using GridViewRow.FindControl method make the link visible or invisible.

Comment: I understand adding that funtionality into the rowdatabount, but do I have to convert the action panel to something else? Is this possible to do with an action panel?

Comment: Not necessarily. Can you share part of you code?

Comment: which part would be helpful

Comment: the part relevant to your question.

Comment: added the relevent ascx- linkbuttonViewApprovers is what I am trying to hide/ show as well as other relevant code- let me know if you would like to see anything else

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an additional model (entity) that represents a row, which adds a visibility flag to each row and then you'll be able to set each row individually.
If you need to pass the data to and from BL and DAL components you can use the [AutoMapper Nuget Package](http://automapper.org/) to map between entities of different layers.

Hope it helps!